# Why if did not execute right condition

Tags: java

i have a code, like this

```
public static Response updateDataFiles(String id, String checksum){
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();

    Files files = (Files) session.get(Files.class, id);
    System.out.println("checksum "+checksum);
    System.out.println("checksum file "+files.getChecksumFile());
    String checksumFile = files.getChecksumFile();
    if(checksum == checksumFile){
        System.out.println("upload success");           
        files.setStatusUpload(EnumStatusUpload.statusUpload.UPLOADED_AND_SUCCESS.toString());                                   
    }else{
        System.out.println("upload success but checksum error");            
        files.setStatusUpload(EnumStatusUpload.statusUpload.UPLOADED_BUT_ERROR_CHECKSUM.toString());
    }
    session.update(files);
    trans.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();

    Response respon = new Response();
    respon.status = 200;
    return respon;
}
```

at `if(checksum == checksumFile)` there's something wrong, the checksum variable and checksumFile have a same value, but if did not execute the right condition, if executed else condition.
In my log i had seen the value of checksum variable, and checksumFile like this

```
checksum      9d73d945294d5488056bb5da54f62e8f
checksum file 9d73d945294d5488056bb5da54f62e8f
```

i don't know what's wrong in my code. Can anyone help me? and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to compare the values of the two strings using [.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
checksum.equals(checksumFile)
```

Using `==` compares the references and basically asks whether the two references point to the same object, which they don't.

Comment: damn, i forget about that, thanks anyway :)